# Ansible json query

Tags: jquery, json, ansible

I have the following json:

```
{
    "entities": {
        "results": [
            {
                "content": "",
                "redirected": false,
                "url": "",
                "status": 200,
                "date": "Fri, 18 Mar 2022 11:55:46 GMT",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "content_length": "6958",
                "connection": "close",
                "set_cookie": "m",
                "x_oneagent_js_injection": "true",
                "response_source": "Cluster",
                "response_id": "TD4QHMLVDNGP",
                "strict_transport_security": "preload",
                "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block",
                "cache_control": "no-store, no-cache",
                "pragma": "no-cache",
                "x_robots_tag": "noindex",
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent",
                "cookies_string": "c8c",
                "cookies": {
                    "dtCookie": "",
                    "apmroute": ""
                },
                "msg": "OK (6958 bytes)",
                "elapsed": 0,
                "changed": false,
                "json": {
                    "totalCount": 1,
                    "pageSize": 50,
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "entityId": "xxxx",
                            "displayName": "xxxx",
                            "toRelationships": {
                                "isNetworkClientOfHost": [
                              
                                ],
                                "isProcessOf": [
                                  
                                ],
                                "isNetworkInterfaceOf": [
                               
                                ],
                                "runsOn": [
                               
                                ],
                                "runsOnHost": [
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE-917FBB145BB92C69",
                                        "type": "SERVICE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE_INSTANCE-C278DFBEF7827B65",
                                        "type": "SERVICE_INSTANCE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE-9EDC19D785C5FE9A",
                                        "type": "SERVICE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE_INSTANCE-517C145645D012A8",
                                        "type": "SERVICE_INSTANCE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE-F39E62B8805CD48D",
                                        "type": "SERVICE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE_INSTANCE-C3193EF273B614BE",
                                        "type": "SERVICE_INSTANCE"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "id": "SERVICE_INSTANCE-94DF9711806A0297",
                                        "type": "SERVICE_INSTANCE"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "isDiskOf": [
                                   
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "url": "",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            "Authorization": ""
                        },
                        "return_content": true,
                        "status_code": [
                            "200"
                        ],
                        "validate_certs": false,
                        "force": false,
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "use_proxy": true,
                        "force_basic_auth": false,
                        "body_format": "raw",
                        "follow_redirects": "safe",
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "follow": false,
                        "unsafe_writes": false,
                        "url_username": null,
                        "url_password": null,
                        "client_cert": null,
                        "client_key": null,
                        "dest": null,
                        "body": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "group": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "attributes": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "directory_mode": null
                    }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "item": "exxx",
                "ansible_loop_var": "item"
            },
            {
                "content": "",
                "redirected": false,
                "url": "",
                "status": 200,
                "date": "Fri, 18 Mar 2022 11:55:46 GMT",
                "content_type": "application/json",
                "transfer_encoding": "chunked",
                "connection": "close",
                "set_cookie": "",
                "dynatrace_response_source": "Cluster",
                "dynatrace_response_id": "",
                "strict_transport_security": "",
                "x_xss_protection": "1; mode=block",
                "cache_control": "no-store, no-cache",
                "pragma": "no-cache",
                "vary": "Accept-Encoding, User-Agent",
                "x_robots_tag": "noindex",
                "cookies_string": "",
                "cookies": {
                    "dtCookie": "-",
                    "apmroute": ""
                },
                "msg": "OK (unknown bytes)",
                "elapsed": 0,
                "changed": false,
                "json": {
                    "totalCount": 1,
                    "pageSize": 50,
                    "entities": [
                        {
                            "entityId": "xxxx",
                            "displayName": "xxxx",
                            "toRelationships": {
                                "isProcessOf": [
                                   
                                ],
                                "isNetworkClientOfHost": [
                                   
                                ],
                                "isDiskOf": [
                                                                    
                                ],
                                "runsOn": [
                                  
                                ],
                                "isNetworkInterfaceOf": [
                                   
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "invocation": {
                    "module_args": {
                        "url": "9&=",
                        "method": "GET",
                        "headers": {
                            "Content-Type": "/json; =utf-8",
                            "Authorization": ""
                        },
                        "return_content": true,
                        "status_code": [
                            "200"
                        ],
                        "validate_certs": false,
                        "force": false,
                        "http_agent": "ansible-httpget",
                        "use_proxy": true,
                        "force_basic_auth": false,
                        "body_format": "raw",
                        "follow_redirects": "safe",
                        "timeout": 30,
                        "follow": false,
                        "unsafe_writes": false,
                        "url_username": null,
                        "url_password": null,
                        "client_cert": null,
                        "client_key": null,
                        "dest": null,
                        "body": null,
                        "src": null,
                        "creates": null,
                        "removes": null,
                        "unix_socket": null,
                        "mode": null,
                        "owner": null,
                        "group": null,
                        "seuser": null,
                        "serole": null,
                        "selevel": null,
                        "setype": null,
                        "attributes": null,
                        "content": null,
                        "backup": null,
                        "remote_src": null,
                        "regexp": null,
                        "delimiter": null,
                        "directory_mode": null
                    }
                },
                "failed": false,
                "item": "xx",
                "ansible_loop_var": "item"
            }
        ],
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "changed": false
    },
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

I want to extract the id's with "type": "SERVICE". When i use the below query i get the result but also including the type: SERVICE_INSTANCE

```
    - debug:
       msg: "{{ entities | json_query('results[].json.entities[].toRelationships.runsOnHost[].id') }}"
```

I tried with the below query as documented on https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

But when i try this the set fact stays empty. I tried with different kind of quots, single, double,.. but it stays empty.

```
- set_fact:
        my_service: "{{ entities | json_query('results[].json.entities[].toRelationships.runsOnHost[?type==''SERVICE''].id') }}"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might succeed using `jmespath` (i.e. the language used by `json_query`) but I'd go with core filters here => `{{ entities.results | map(attribute='json.entities') | flatten | selectattr('toRelationships.runsOnHost', 'defined') | map(attribute='toRelationships.runsOnHost') | flatten | selectattr('type', 'eq', 'SERVICE') | map(attribute='id') }}`

Comment: I also succeeded with `json_query` your problem is escaping correctly. For an all in one inlined expression, you can replace single quotes with back ticks as show in the specification to mark strings inside doutble quotes inside single quotes. The following should give you the expected result: `"{{ entities.results | json_query('[].json.entities[].toRelationships.runsOnHost[?type==\`SERVICE\`].id') }}"`

Comment: @Zeitounator the backticks did the job!